# the following function should call itself only under a condition but goes in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I have to design a cash register drawer function `checkCashRegister()` that accepts purchase price as the first argument (`price`), payment as the second argument (`cash`), and cash-in-drawer (cid`)` as the third argument.

`cid` is a 2D array listing available currency.

The `checkCashRegister()` function should always return an object with a status key and a change key.

Return `{status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS", change: []}` if cash-in-drawer is less than the change due, or if you cannot return the exact change.

Return `{status: "CLOSED", change: [...]}` with cash-in-drawer as the value for the key change if it is equal to the change due.

Otherwise, return `{status: "OPEN", change: [...]}`, with the change due in coins and bills, sorted in highest to lowest order, as the value of the change key

This is my code:

```js
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  var change = cash - price;
  var totalCash = 0;
  var statusChange = {
    status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS",
    change: []
  };
  var index = 0;
  //ARRAY CONTAINING THE NAME OF THE CURRENCIES AND THE RESPECTIVE VALUES
  var currency = [{ name: "PENNY", value: 0.01},
                  { name: "NICKEL", value: 0.05},
                  { name: "DIME", value: 0.1},
                  { name: "QUARTER", value: 0.25},
                  { name: "ONE", value: 1},
                  { name: "FIVE", value: 5},
                  { name: "TEN", value: 10},
                  { name: "TWENTY", value: 20},
                  { name: "ONE HUNDRED", value: 100}];

  //verify total money in drawer
  for (let i = 0; i < cid.length; i++) {
    totalCash += cid[i][1];
  }
  //compare amount of total money with change 
  //if the total amount of money is less than change I return the defualt            statusChange
  if (totalCash < change)
    return statusChange;
  //if the amounts are equal the status closes and I return the cid array
  else if (totalCash == change) {
    statusChange["status"] = "CLOSED";
    statusChange["change"] = cid;
    return statusChange;
  }
  //if the drawer has enought money but the amount is different then   change the status passes to OPEN
  else {
    statusChange["status"] = "OPEN";
  }

  //given the change value it returns the index of the array cid from which it should start taking the money out
  function selectCurrency(change) {
    if (change >= 100)
      return index = 8;
    else if (change >= 20 && change <= 99)
      return index = 7;
    else if (change >= 10 && change <= 19)
      return index = 6;
    else if (change >= 5 && change <= 9)
      return index = 5;
    else if (change >= 1 && change <= 4)
      return index = 4;
    else if (change >= 0.25 && change <= 0.99)
      return index = 3;
    else if (change >= 0.1 && change <= 0.24)
      return index = 2;
    else if (change >= 0.05 && change <= 0.09)
      return index = 1;
    else if (change > 0 && change <= 0.04)
      return index = 0;
  }

  //first call of selectCurrency to assign index a value and pass it to the next function
  selectCurrency(change);

  ///// THE INFINITE LOOP IS IN THIS FUNCTION
  function getChange(change, index) {
    var count = 0;
    //first I check that there is money of a specific currency and if not a pass to the next one calling again the funcion
    if (cid[index][1] == 0) {
      index -= 1;
      getChange(change, index);
    }
    //if there is money I check how much of that currency to take out
    else {
      /*note the index matches cid array and the currency array to make it work
       this while says that till change minus the specific value of a currency is bigger or equal to 0 &&
      the import of that currency in the drawer minus the (same as above) .. then I subtract it either to change
      and the drawer
      count which was initialized with 0 is gonna increase by one at every cycle for the following instruction*/

      while (change - currency[index]["value"] >= 0 && cid[index][1] - currency[index]["value"] >= 0) {
        cid[index][1] -= currency[index]["value"];
        change -= currency[index]["value"];
        count++;
        change = Math.round(change * 100) / 100;
      }
      //push in statusChange, which had an empty array the name of the currency and the value
      statusChange.change.push([currency[index]["name"], count * currency[index]["value"]]);

      console.log(JSON.stringify(statusChange));
    }
    //if change equal to 0 no need to continue and return status
    if (change == 0)
      return statusChange;
    //if index arrived to 0 && change is bigger than the total amount of PENNY it means I don't have the right or enough change
    else if (index == 0 && change > cid[0][1])
      return {
        status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS",
        change: []
      };
    //the function calls itself passing the change left and the index given by the selectCurrency function
    else
      getChange(change, selectCurrency(change));
  }

  return getChange(change, index);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(getChange(change, index)));
}

checkCashRegister(3.26, 100, [
  ["PENNY", 1.01],
  ["NICKEL", 2.05],
  ["DIME", 3.1],
  ["QUARTER", 4.25],
  ["ONE", 90],
  ["FIVE", 55],
  ["TEN", 20],
  ["TWENTY", 60],
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
]);
```

the function should call itself only under satisfied conditions. But when the change is equal to 0 or there is no exact change the function should stop, instead for some reason it the recursion goes infinite.

PLEASE help me to understand the mistake and how to solve it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The `console.log()` statement will never be executed, since it's after `return`.

Comment: You're calling `selectCurrency()`, but never assigning the return value anywhere.

Comment: Oh, I see, `selectCurrency()` assigns to `index` while it's returning. Don't do that. Just do `return 8`, and then do `index = selectCurrency()`.

Comment: I actually found the solution. Yep sorry I was just cutting and pasting consolo checks everywhere xD

Comment: for some reason with a funciton declaration it goes on infinite loop. I tried to assign the function to a variable and to make the callback through the variable and it works just fine. I also changed some other conditions to obtain the wanted result

Comment: It should work the same with a function declaration and variable. But you should post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED - the issues wasn't about function delcaration or expression. The function was missing the "else if" condition you can see below. Before the condition was put at the end causing a the infinite loop. Besides, the last if/else and wasn't working properly.

```
var trial = function getChange(change,index){
             var count = 0;    
             if(cid[index][1] == 0){
                index -= 1; 
                trial(change,index);
             }
             else if(index == 0 && change > cid[index][1]){
                statusChange.status = "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS";
                statusChange.change = [];
                return statusChange;    
             }
             else{

               while(change - currency[index]["value"] >= 0 && cid[index][1] - currency[index]["value"] >= 0 ){  
                 cid[index][1] -= currency[index]["value"];
                 change -= currency[index]["value"];
                 count++;
                 change = Math.round(change*100)/100;
             }

               statusChange.change.push([currency[index]["name"],count*currency[index]["value"]]);
               if(change == 0)
                 return statusChange;
               else{
                 trial(change, selectCurrency(change));
               }
              }
             }

           trial(change, index); 
           return statusChange;
           }
```